# Can we derive Ampere's Circuital Law from Gauss's Law or vice versa?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, gauss-law, maxwell-equations

I was curious if it is possible to derive Ampere's Circuital Law from Gauss's Law as they are very similar and both can be applied for highly symmetrical problems $(Infinite\space wires,Rings..etc)$ and also because they look very similar.
$$\oint B\space dl=\sum \mu I$$

$$\oint E \space dA=\frac{\sum Q}{\epsilon}$$

Comment: Gauss law holds for electrostatics.. And ampere's law holds for magnetostatics.. Both are different views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

The most important reason is that they're equivalent to two Maxwell equations, respectively Maxwell-Gauss and Maxwell-Ampere. Since Maxwell equations are independent from each others, they can't be derived from one another.

Also, the resemblance between those two laws aren't as deep as they seem:

- Ampere law is a line integral.
- Gauss Law is a surface integral.

There are strong *mathematical* parallels, but nothing more.

Comment: They aren't as independant as you'd think.

Comment: If you need other equations to make the derivation the OP was asking about, then you can't say that one is a consequence of the other. Your answer above is interesting, though. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

These 2 equations alone are not  mathematically  related , so  no. However what I believe you're trying to ask is:

"can I obtain information about maxwells equations, using a different maxwell equation."

**Obtaining Gauss law for magnetism**:

$$ \nabla × \vec{E} = - \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$$

Taking the divergence

$$0 = \frac{\partial \nabla \cdot\vec{B}}{\partial t}$$

$$C(x,y,z) = \nabla \cdot \vec{B}$$

Which is gauss law for magnetism, where $C = 0$

**Obtaining Gauss law :**

Doing the same with amperes law, gives

$$ \nabla × \vec{B} = \mu_{0}\vec{J} + \mu_{0}\epsilon_{0}\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}$$

$$ 0 = \mu_{0} \nabla \cdot \vec{J} + \mu_{0}\epsilon_{0}\frac{\partial \nabla \cdot  \vec{E}}{\partial t}$$

$$ - \frac{1}{\epsilon_{0}}\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = \frac{\partial \nabla \cdot  \vec{E}}{\partial t}$$

Substitute charge conservation: $\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = -\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$

$$  \frac{1}{\epsilon_{0}}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}
 = \frac{\partial \nabla \cdot  \vec{E}}{\partial t}$$

$$  \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}} + C(x,y,z)
 =  \nabla \cdot  \vec{E}$$

These constants of integration, are the reason that the other maxwell equations are important,as they specify what these constants are.